# Unable to convert soap response string to xml in Yii2

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

I have a soap request. I am able to send the request and get a response in a string. Now I want to convert it into XML and get the required data from it.

**Response**

```
string(1383) "
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResponseMessage xmlns:ns="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message Message.xsd">
<Header>
    <Verb>reply</Verb>
    <Noun>EndDeviceControls</Noun>
    <Revision>2.0</Revision>
    <Timestamp>2019-05-04T10:39:11+04:30</Timestamp>
    <Source>HES-BSTC</Source>
    <AsyncReplyFlag>true</AsyncReplyFlag>
    <ReplyAddress>http://ip:port/AmiWeb/services/Metering</ReplyAddress>
    <User>
        <UserID>user</UserID>
    </User>
    <MessageID>6C3F761B-A1EC-4EBE-BB49-67B720C5AE62</MessageID>
    <CorrelationID>1001</CorrelationID>
    <Property>
        <Name>password</Name>
        <Value>password</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>timeout(m)</Name>
        <Value>30</Value>
    </Property>
</Header>
<Reply>
    <Result>OK</Result>
    <Error>
        <code>0.3</code>
    </Error>
</Reply>
</ResponseMessage>"
```

**Code**

```
$xml_post_string = /** @lang text */
                           '<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:soap="http://soap.inf.hexing.cn">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <soap:doCommand>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <arg0><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RequestMessage
xmlns="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message"
xmlns:m="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/EndDeviceControls#"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message Message.xsd">
<Header>
<Verb>create</Verb>
<Noun>EndDeviceControls</Noun>
<Revision>2.0</Revision>
<Timestamp>2016-01-01T00:00:00+04:30</Timestamp>
<Source>MDM</Source>
<AsyncReplyFlag>true</AsyncReplyFlag>
<ReplyAddress>http://ip:port/AmiWeb/services/Metering</ReplyAddress>
<AckRequired>true</AckRequired>
<User>
<UserID>'.$userName.'</UserID>
</User>
<MessageID>83c643e6-85c5-43c0-9e0a-fa1deb469b72</MessageID>
<CorrelationID>1001</CorrelationID>
<Property>
<Name>password</Name>
<Value>'.$password.'</Value>
</Property>
<Property>
<Name>timeout(m)</Name>
<Value>30</Value>
</Property>
</Header>
<Payload>
<m:EndDeviceControls>
<m:EndDeviceControl>
<m:reason>Disconnect/Reconnect</m:reason>
<m:EndDeviceControlType ref="3.0.211.23"/>
<m:EndDevices>
<m:mRID>'.$msn.'</m:mRID>
<m:Names>
<m:name>Disconnect</m:name>
<m:NameType>
<m:name>ControlType</m:name>
</m:NameType>
</m:Names>
</m:EndDevices>
</m:EndDeviceControl>
</m:EndDeviceControls>
</Payload>
</RequestMessage>
     ]]></arg0>
  </soap:doCommand>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
 $headers = array(
                           "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                           "Accept: text/xml",
                           "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                           "Pragma: no-cache",
                           //"SOAPAction: http://connecting.website.com/WSDL_Service/GetPrice",
                           "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                       ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

                       $url = $soapUrl;

                       // PHP cURL  for https connection

                       $ch = curl_init();
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

                       // converting
                       $response = curl_exec($ch);
                       curl_close($ch);
                       $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
                       var_dump($xml);
                       die();
```

**Output**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#121 (0) { }
```

The output is empty. Now I want two things

1. To convert string to XML
2. From the returned XML I want to get the value of `<AsyncReplyFlag>true</AsyncReplyFlag>` from the response

**Update 1**

As per suggestion, I have added below code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
                        echo $xml->asXML();
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResponseMessage xmlns:ns="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message Message.xsd">
<Header>
    <Verb>reply</Verb>
    <Noun>EndDeviceControls</Noun>
    <Revision>2.0</Revision>
    <Timestamp>2019-05-04T14:01:48+04:30</Timestamp>
    <Source>HES-BSTC</Source>
    <AsyncReplyFlag>true</AsyncReplyFlag>
    <ReplyAddress>http://ip:port/AmiWeb/services/Metering</ReplyAddress>
    <User>
        <UserID>user</UserID>
    </User>
    <MessageID>F4E15012-D009-4CBC-A610-E937F2620193</MessageID>
    <CorrelationID>1001</CorrelationID>
    <Property>
        <Name>password</Name>
        <Value>password</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>timeout(m)</Name>
        <Value>30</Value>
    </Property>
</Header>
<Reply>
    <Result>OK</Result>
    <Error>
        <code>0.3</code>
    </Error>
</Reply>
</ResponseMessage>
```

**What I have tried?**

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
print_r($xml);
die();
```

It gives me an empty result

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
                       $doc->loadXML($response);
                       $XMLresults = $doc->getElementsByTagName("AsyncReplyFlag")->item(0)->textContent;
                       echo $XMLresults;
                       die();
```

It gives me an error

> Trying to get property of non-object
>   $XMLresults = $doc->getElementsByTagName("AsyncReplyFlag")->item(0)->textContent;

Still, I am unable to get the value of `<AsyncReplyFlag>true</AsyncReplyFlag>`

How can I achieve it? 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 1: the string already is XML. 2: `$asyncReplyFlag=(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($response))->getElementsByTagName("AsyncReplyFlag")->item(0)->textContent;`

Comment: @hanshenrik not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMDocument should have no problem extracting it, as a quick one-liner:

```
echo (@DOMDocument::loadXML($response))->getElementsByTagName("AsyncReplyFlag")->item(0)->textContent;
```

... or if you want to meticulously check for errors every step of the way,

```
$xml_errors=[];
set_error_handler(function(int $errno, string $errstr, string $errfile, int $errline, array $errcontext) use(&$xml_errors){
    ob_start();
    call_user_func_array('var_dump',func_get_args());
    $xml_errors[]=ob_get_clean();
});
$domd=new DOMDocument();
$loaded=$domd->loadXML($response);
restore_error_handler();
if(!$loaded){
    if(defined('STDERR')){
        fprintf(STDERR,"%s",$response);
    }
    throw new \RuntimeException("errors parsing XML! xml printed in stderr, parsing errors: ".print_r($xml_errors,true));    
}
$ele=$domd->getElementsByTagName("AsyncReplyFlag");
if($ele->length<1){
    if(defined('STDERR')){
        fprintf(STDERR,"%s",$response);
    }
    throw new \RuntimeException("did not get AsyncReplyFlag in response! (xml printed in stderr)");
}
echo $ele->item(0)->textContent;
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on boolean`

Comment: For your second option, I am getting this error `Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR'`

Comment: @Faisal weird, there's 2 things here: DOMDocument don't think your xml is valid xml, and your STDERR is not defined, something weird with the way you're executing php but whatever, try #2 again, what do you get this time?

Comment: @Faisal are you sure? still getting `Use of undefined constant STDERR` after the `if(defined('STDERR'))` patch?

Comment: @Faisal then there is something very wrong with your php installation, where STDERR is defined but you get an error when actually trying to use it... can you try [contacting me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067003/hanshenrik?tab=profile), i'd like to investigate

Comment: sent you an email

Answer (score 1):

Trying to output a SimpleXMLElement using `var_dump()` isn't a good idea and as you have seen - doesn't give much.

If you just want to see the XML it has loaded, instead use...

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

which will show you the XML has loaded OK, so then to output the field your after is just

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
echo $xml->Header->AsyncReplyFlag;
```

Comment: `echo $xml->Header->AsyncReplyFlag;` it's giving me empty result

Comment: Check the XML has some content using `echo $xml->asXML();`

Comment: Just to check the next part - try `echo $xml->Header->asXML();`

Comment: OK, looks as though it's having problems with the names, can you check this by `echo $xml->children()[0]->getName();`

Comment: It gives me error `syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192826/discussion-between-nigel-ren-and-faisal).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `XPath` query

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlData);
echo $xml->xpath('//AsyncReplyFlag')[0];
```

OR

You can use `xml_parser_create`

```
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $values, $indexes);// $xml containing the XML
xml_parser_free($p);

echo $values[12]['value'];
```

For other details, you can `print_r($values)`

Comment: `$response = curl_exec($ch);
                           curl_close($ch);
                           $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
                           $p = xml_parser_create();
                           xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $values, $indexes);// $xml containing the XML
                           xml_parser_free($p);


                           print_r($values);
                           die();`

It gives me `Array ( )`

Comment: something is wrong with the response if its correct XML you should get the result

Comment: the XML response is in string `string(1383) "` you can see my question I have also added the response

Comment: @Faisal remove the string(1383) from the response

Comment: I have got this response after `$response = curl_exec($ch);
                           curl_close($ch); var_dump($response);`

Comment: you can pass $response

Comment: How can I pass it ?

Comment: xml_parse_into_struct($p, $response, $values, $indexes);

Comment: $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

Comment: `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response); print_r($xml);
                           die();` gives me `SimpleXMLElement Object ( )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192825/discussion-between-rakesh-jakhar-and-faisal).