# XML to array using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I need to convert XML to array,but its not converting

here is my code

```
<?php
$response='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<soap:Body>
<Search xmlns="http:url">
  <Request>
    <aaa>string</aaa>
    <bbb>string</bbb>
    <ccc>srting</ccc>
    <SourceName>string</SourceName>

  </Request>
</Search>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';


function xml2Array($xmlstring)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    return json_decode($json,TRUE);
}
$arr = xml2Array($response);
print_r($arr);
```

But if i remove

```
<soap:Body>
```

from the XML it works fine, What is the issue how to resole it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Comment: Unfortunately, SimpleXML is no longer simple when namespaces are involved. It's possible that you simply cannot use the `json_encode($xml)` trick. Do you really need to generic solution for any XML definition?

Comment: @AlvaroGonzalez Is there any alternate available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892639/converting-soap-xml-response-to-a-php-object-or-array).

In your case try this code

```
<?php
$response='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<soap:Body>
<Search xmlns="http:url">
  <Request>
    <aaa>string</aaa>
    <bbb>string</bbb>
    <ccc>srting</ccc>
    <SourceName>string</SourceName>

  </Request>
</Search>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';


function xml2Array($xmlstring)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap-env', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
    $bodies = $xml->xpath('//soap-env:Body');
    if (is_array($bodies) && !empty($bodies[0])) {
        $json = json_encode($bodies[0]);
        return json_decode($json,TRUE);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
$arr = xml2Array($response);
print_r($arr);
```

And output will be:

```
Array
(
    [Search] => Array
        (
            [Request] => Array
                (
                    [aaa] => string
                    [bbb] => string
                    [ccc] => srting
                    [SourceName] => string
                )

        )

)
```